# alternate value even or odd week number from startdate

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to assemble a table that shows the amount of hours an employee has to work in each week of the year.
There are 2 tables for this:

First table:

```
EMPLOYEEID  REGIMENO    DATEACTIVE              
700944      04          2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

another table

```
REGIMENO    Week1   Week2
01          40      40
02          32      32
03          32      32
04          40      32
```

I want to achieve something like:

```
EMPLOYEEID WEEKNUMBER HOURS
700944     1          40
700944     2          32
700944     3          40
700944     4          32
....
```

So i'm kinda stuck how to first of all join every week to it, and second of all keep in mind that not every scheme starts on the same date for each employee...

Any ideas?

Thx in advance

Comment: Which database system are you using?

Comment: Can you explain what are the columns in second tables are storing? What is `Week1` and `Week2` represent.

Comment: @jpw I'm using SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: @Vladimir Oselsky, Week1 and Week2 represent the amount of hours an employee has to work within one week, there are 2 weeks because some people have a different scheme for the first than for the second (parttime work etc), so there's a loop Week1,Week2,Week1,Week2,..